# Testing Mongoid scopes without actually hitting the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, factory-bot

Is there a smart way to test a scopes without hitting the db?

I am asking because I am dealing with scopes on multi-level of embedded documents, and to actually create the objects in db would require a long chain of objects to be created first.
This seems inefficient performance wise, and really cumbersome to write to test a single scope.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the implications of your multi-level of embedded documents, but you can assert that a scope is a Mongoid::Criteria, and further assert that it is a criteria with certain properties.

RSpec examples:

```
  expect(Charge.successful).to be_a Mongoid::Criteria
  expect(Charge.successful).to eq Mongoid::Criteria.new(Charge).where(state: 'successful')
```

Note that this isn't testing behaviour, which would be best practice.

A better approach might simply be to bite the bullet and use something like [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to create your objects and test behaviour. Presumably to fully acceptance test your system you'll need these objects anyway.

If you'd like to avoid 'hitting the DB', you could use [EmbeddedMongo](https://github.com/gdb/embedded-mongo). This would probably speed up your tests and mean you wouldn't need MongoDB on your CI server.